# Remove clipPath on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

In short I have an image that is masked using `clipPath` so that it works in IE 9+. The issue is I need to have the mask hide on hover so that it reveals the full image, then reapply on mouseout. The script I have right now does not work. Pen is included below. I am very new to SVG and `clipPath`.

http://codepen.io/OMGDrAcula/pen/eJPzQx

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.finish')
    .mouseover(function() {
      $(this).find('svg').find('clipPath').css('display', 'none');
    }).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).find('svg').find('clipPath').css('display', 'block');
    });
})
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-3 finish" style="position:relative;border:1px solid red;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/297x252" class="img-responsive" />
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" style="width:100%;height:252px;top:0;left:0;position:absolute;border:dotted 2px blue" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="297" height="252" x="0px" y="0px" style="enable-background:new 0 0 297 252;"
  viewBox="0 0 297 252" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="maskID0">
        <rect width="100%" height="252" x="0" y="0" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <title>Test Image</title>
    <desc>Test 123</desc>
    <image clip-path="url(#maskID0)" width="297" height="252" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/297x252"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not remove `clip-path` attribute on mouse-over and reapply it on mouse-out?

Comment: So something like this?

$(.finish).mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find('svg').removeAttr("clip-path");
});

Comment: Something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/jWeMJN) (*I've modified the width of the clip-path but you get the idea*). Does that help?

Comment: @harry Just to make sure I understand what you are doing. On hover you are setting the clip-path to not have a url on mousenter, then adding the original url back on mouseout correct?

Comment: Yep (or) you can remove the attribute on mouse-enter and add it back along with the original URL on mouse-out.

Comment: Awesome that is what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you be able to add that as an answer so that I can accept it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `display` property of the `clipPath` element itself has no effect because the `clipPath` is only a definition and it doesn't have any display of its own. It is the `image` that gets displayed after being clipped by the defined `clipPath`. So, a simple solution would be to just remove the `clip-path` attribute on mouse-in and then add it (along with the original clip path URL) back again on mouse-out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.finish').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('svg image').removeAttr('clip-path');
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('svg image').attr('clip-path', 'url(#maskID0)');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-3 finish" style="position:relative;border:1px solid red;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/297x252" class="img-responsive" />
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" style="width:100%;height:252px;top:0;left:0;position:absolute;border:dotted 2px blue" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="297" height="252" x="0px" y="0px" style="enable-background:new 0 0 297 252;"
  viewBox="0 0 297 252" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="maskID0">
        <rect width="150" height="252" x="0" y="0" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <title>Test Image</title>
    <desc>Test 123</desc>
    <image clip-path="url(#maskID0)" width="297" height="252" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/297x252"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```